# EditText box cursor appear after touching box?

Tags: android

I am using EditText in my app. I want that the cursor appears only after user touches the edit text box. how could I do this?
I have used this to hide the cursor first.

```
EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:ems="10"
```

how could I show it after touch?

Comment: Add an `OnTouchListener()` to your `EditText` and the first time it is touched, call `setCursorVisible(true)`.

Comment: In your xml file inside your EditText tag you might propably be having a <requestFocus /> tag. Delete this and the cursor will no longer point to your edit text.

Comment: but now the cursor is not appearing at all after i tap on edit text box

Answer (score 3):

Try to request focus for other views instead of letting your edittext get the focus in the first time view loaded. `<requestFocus />` put this to your main view.

Answer (score 1):

Try : `edittext.clearFocus();` you can put it in the onCreate() it will set focus to the first view.

Implement :

```
    mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        mText.requestFocus()

      return true;
      }
  };
  mText.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```

Comment: but now the cursor is not appearing at all after i tap on edit text box.

Comment: You can implement OnTouchListener() to your EditText and then use the following to set focus to the edittext :  editText.requestFocus()

Answer (score 0):

Go to Layout file of your project and remove `<requestFocus />` from the `EditTexts` for which you want the cursor to appear only when the user taps on the EditText box.

Answer (score 0):

If in your layout file

```
<requestFocus />
```

is there, then just remove from the Edittext and because of this the cusrsor is only visible when user tap on to Edittext.